# Privilages on phpMyAdmin not visible

Tags: phpmyadmin

I created a database named `coffeeOrder` and when I went to change the privileges for the local host to change the password the 'edit privilege' option is not visible.

[image: The screenshot link is provided kindly view it and help me.]

Answer (score 0):

The user you're connected as lacks the global `GRANT` privilege, and perhaps `SUPER` as well (though I think it's just GRANT in this case). Since you're on the demo server, I wouldn't worry about it since I'm not sure offhand if even the root user usually has this permission (it's possible someone removed it, in which case the demo server will reset at some point). If it would be your own server, I'd suggest logging in as the root user or resetting your privileges.